# How do I get rid of the extra comma?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, data-cleaning, python-re

So I have a dataframe with a column that looks like this:

| Combined Column |
| --- |
| , on bounce list |
| looks fine |
| , invalid syntax |
| , on bounce list, invalid syntax |
| invalid domain, , invalid dns |
| looks fine |
| invalid domain, |

I want to get rid of the extra comma, but I'm not sure how to.

I tried using replace but this doesn't work since it gets rid of all the comma:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].replace(',','')
```

I then tried to use re and it works well except for a few issue (leaves the comma in the last row and removes the space in the third last row). This is my code (I have tried other patterns, but no other ones works as well as this one):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(^| ).(( ).)*( |$)')

def remove_extra_commas(text):
    return pattern3.sub('', text)

df['column'] = df['column'].apply(remove_extra_commas)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip(','))
```